# How to make autofill INDEX(MATCH) or Lookup if the column is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As you know `arrayformula` allows the formula to autofill for new lines in the tab.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:A<>"","111",""))
```

So whenever you have new entry (line) in column A, "111" will be auto-filled in respective row.

I want to write the formula with autofill to lookup the new data, but `ArrayFormula` does not work with `Index(match)` and `xlookup`. So I have 1 table (Table 1) with all data:

**Table 1**

| Country | PnL line | 1/1/2022 | 1/2/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country A | Revenue | 13 | 15 |
| Country B | Revenue | 4 | 7 |

and the output table (Table 2) is:

| Country | Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Country A | 1/1/2022 | 13 |
| Country B | 1/1/2022 | 4 |

I tried this formula for cell C2

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A<>"",INDEX(TABLE1!C2:D,MATCH(1(TABLE1!A2:A=A2:A)*(TABLE1!B2:B=C$1)*(TABLE1!C1:1=B2:B),0))
```

however it lookup only the first entry.

The row in the second table will be added each month automatically. So I just want to know is there any ways to make `arrayformula` to lookup the data whenever new line is added? So if I have new line "Country B" and and "1/2/2022" the output should be as follows:

| Country | Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Country A | 1/1/2022 | 13 |
| Country B | 1/1/2022 | 4 |
| Country B | 1/2/2022 | 7 |

Comment: Sorry this isn't that clear. Why isn't `Country A` listed for 1/2/2022 with revenue of 15?

Answer (score 1):

If `Sheet1` has your table data; you may use the following formula in different tab.

```
=query(reduce({"Country","Date","Revenue"},sequence(counta(Sheet1!A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,c,{a;reduce(makearray(1,3,lambda(r,c,iferror(1/0))),sequence(counta(Sheet1!C1:1)),lambda(x,y,{x;index(Sheet1!A2:A,c),index(Sheet1!C1:1,,y),index(Sheet1!C2:1000,c,y)}))})),"Where Col1<>'' order by Col2")
```

- `C1:1` part of the formula dynamically includes the future date(s) you add in at a later time.

[image]

Comment: thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! 

Do you know if it is possible lookup a column only, because there might be case where the sheet1 may contain another PnL line such as CoS?

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output (manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed.

Comment: Sure https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qTnxdBRP84xT-GysTBtsjEXr_bCO77bzAz6bI6zjlVE/edit#gid=1669716896

Comment: The shared sheet has restricted access

Comment: Sorry, I granted the access

Comment: you may try this in `Cell C2` of output tab and drag it down-wards & side-ways `=ifna(filter(filter(Input!$A:$Z;Input!$1:$1=$B2);Input!$A:$A=$A2;Input!$B:$B=C$1))`